# Translation of "for some" as an existential quantifier

Tags: declension, mathematics

In English one can write the existential statement ∃ *x* ∈ *A* : *P*(*x*) as follows:

> *P*(*x*) for some *x* ∈ *A*.

Is there a similar construction in German? My best guess is:

> *P*(*x*)  für irgendein *x* ∈ *A*.

1. Is this use of *irgendein* correct? Does it correctly reflect the meaning of existential quantifier?
2. Does *irgendein* need to be declined in this case and, if so, how? I don't know what grammatical gender *x* should take. Is it *das Element x*, *die Variable x* or *der Buchstabe x* ?
3. How would it be for more than one variable, e.g. ∃ *x*,*y* ∈ *A* : *P*(*x*) ?

**EDIT**

To clarify: It's important to distinguish here between a universal statement and an existential statement. I'll be more specific about why I would like a translation of the "for some" construction by providing a concrete example:

> Let *B* = {(*n*,2*n*) : *n* ∈ *N*} and let *b* ∈ *N*. Then *b* = 2*m* for some *m* ∈ *N*.

Here *m* is not an arbitrary element, since it depends on *b*. I want to avoid constructions such as "Es existiert *m* ..." because I want to introduce *b* before *m* in a concise way.

Comment: "beliebiges" is much more common, see orithena's answer. As a non-english speaker, "for some" does not sound very existential.

Comment: This use of "for some" is ubiquitous in mathematics written in English. (I am a mathematician and native English speaker.) My trouble with the word "beliebig" in this context is that it suggests that _x_ is arbitrary, which it is not.

Comment: @dwolfeu That's correct. Don't use "beliebig" in this context.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm "for some" is unambiguously existential. The problematic phrase is "for any", which can indeed be interpreted as existential or universal (and should therefore be avoided).

Comment: I'm thinking the best way to answer this kind of thing to to go on German Wikipedia and read some math articles. For example [this article](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gruppe_(Mathematik)) uses *es geben* and *existieren* about equally often. Mathematical jargon isn't a constant though, and a lot depends on the field and the time period.

Comment: @dwolfeu: thanks for clarifying that usage. I left out any additional explanation like "while it does not sound that way - I sure believe you because you are the english speaker and not me". So reading my comment again I also left out my merely surprise about the wording itself. Sorry about that.

Comment: The last time I did math it was _Es gibt ein_ or _Es gibt ein oder mehrere_ - Do not use _irgendein_ or _beliebig_ as it may imply _any_ which implies _all_

Comment: @ShegitBrahm No worries! :)

Comment: I'd probably use _bestimmte_, _gewisse_ or _manche_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your unease is justified, “irgendein” would be unclear, as it could be read as “any” and hence universal quantification. At least it would be so unusual that you should not use it. That aside, you need to decline, but luckily all letters are neuter, so “für irgendein x” is grammatically correct.

Unfortunately, it has been a while since I have written any mathematics in German, and I am not sure what the best option is. You could just write “für ein x“, but that is not as clear as “for some x”. A more precise version is

> für (ein) geeignetes x

or in plural

> für geeignete x,y.

It sounds more formal than “for some”, so I believe it is less common. It is possible that it sounds a bit old-fashioned, but you can definitely use it. I think I would mostly go with the longer “es existiert x, so dass” construction.

Answer (score 14):

The formal statement ∃ *x* ∈ *A* : *P*(*x*) using the existential quantifier reads as

> Es existiert ein *x* ∈ *A*, so dass *P*(*x*) gilt

or

> Es gibt ein *x* ∈ *A*, so dass *P*(*x*) gilt.

It is unnecessary to say *mindestens ein* or something like that. You can also say

> *P*(*x*) für ein *x* ∈ *A*.

or

> Es gilt *P*(*x*) für ein *x* ∈ *A*.

Saying *für irgendein* would be highly unusual. If you really want, you can say *für mindestens ein*, but it is completely unnecessary.

Comment: "It is unnecessary to say mindestens ein or something like that" But it is not uncommon to clearly distinguish from "Es gibt genau ein" (_There is exactly one_).

Comment: @rexkogitans Correct. To express *uniqueness quantification* one often uses the quantifier ∃ ! . That is, one writes ∃ ! *x P(x)* . It includes more than ∃, therefore it needs the additional "genau". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniqueness_quantification .

Comment: Typo: exis*t*iert

Comment: @xehpuk Thank you, corrected!

Comment: @rexkogitans When I teach my students first-order logic I have to emphasize "at least one" a few times. But after that is should be understood without further clarification that "∃ x ∈ A" means "there exists at least one x in A". So it is only necessary when teaching beginners.

Comment: Couldn't "für ein" be misinterpreted as meaning the condition is true for exactly one x in A?

Comment: @MichaelKay Not in a mathematical context. And the phrase "*P(x)* für ein *x ∈ A*" is not used in everyday language.

Answer (score 7):

From my days with formal math at school and university I remember wordings like

> Es existiert mindestens ein x ∈ A, für das gilt: (...)

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it is correct, and it is in my opinion the clearest way to state the fact if you want to avoid the lengthier "Es existiert ein x, für das P(x) gilt". Other possibilities are "für ein x ∈ A" or "für ein geeignetes x ∈ A" (as suggested by Carsten S). Do not use "für x ∈ A" or "für ein beliebiges x ∈ A"; these are more likely to be interpreted as universal.
2. It must be declined, but since you need neuter gender for a variable without further specification, "irgendein" is correct. If you specify the type, say "für irgendein Element x", "für irgendeine Matrix A", or "für irgendeine natürliche Zahl n", it depends on the gender of "Element", "Matrix", or "Zahl".
3. "P(x,y,z) für irgendwelche x, y, z" or "P(x,y,z) für geeignete x, y, z" is fine.

Comment: Wouldn't "irgendein" imply that P(x) holds true for _any_ x ∈ A one could choose, meaning for _all_ x ∈ A? Then, it would express ∀ x ∈ A : P(x) rather than ∃ x ∈ A : P(x), wouldn't it? In addition to the wording I mentioned in my answer, maybe "einige" would fit better than "irgendein".

Comment: Why is not "für irgendeines Element x"?

Comment: Is there a difference between "für irgendein" and "für irgend ein"?

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck I cannot imagine a context where I'd interpret "für irgendein x ∈ A" as equivalent to "für jedes x ∈ A". I would also avoid "für einige", since it might be misinterpreted as "für mehr als ein". One could use "für mindestens ein", however.

Comment: @dwolfeu "irgendein" is declined in the same way as "ein": "für ein x -> für irgendein x".

Comment: @dwolfeu "irgendein" is the correct spelling; "irgend ein" is non-standard.

Comment: @Uwe But "irgendein" (especially in contrast to just "ein") means "any member of a group, regardless which member", correct? Think for example of an illusionist's trick, "Nehmen Sie eine Karte, irgendeine" - "Take a card, any card". So, if you say that "irgendein" element of the set fulfills some condition, you basically say "regardless which element of the set you chose, it fulfills the condition". That will only work if _all_ elements fulfill the condition. Also, the question speaks of "for some x", so there's already a plural there.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck The _some_ in _for some_ isn't necessarily plural. It's the same use of _some_ as in _I just met some guy._ (see https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/some > Determiner > Definition 4).

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck As a native speaker of German and as a theoretical computer scientist, I disagree with your interpretation of "irgendein".

Answer (score 0):

I can't really agree with any of the suggestions so far.

- “Es existiert ein *x*...” suggests there's exactly one, which the ∃ statement doesn't imply. Better would be “es existieren *x* ∈ *A*...”. Both are clunky, nowhere near as natural as “some” in English.
- “Es gibt ein *x*...” has the same uniqueness problem. This isn't as awkward as “existiert”, in fact, if anything it's a bit too colloquial.
- “*P*(*x*) für irgendein *x*...” is even more colloquial, and very unclear what's actually meant logically.
- “Für geeignete *x*” is nice language-wise, but it doesn't really express existance, it's rather something like ∀ *x* ∈ *A* : *P*(*x*) ⇒ *Q*(*x*), where *Q* is whatever property is discussed afterwards in the text.
- “*P*(*x*) für ein beliebiges *x* aus *A*” is even worse, this suggests ∃ *x* ∈ *A* ∧ ∀ *x* ∈ *A* : *P*(*x*), which is much a much stronger proposition.

What I would write depends on the context.

- In the initial statement of a theorem, be precise. “Für *A*-quibilotschige *P* existiert immer *x* ∈ *A* sodass *P*(*x*) erfüllt ist.”
- If this is the final conclusion, then I would just write “...daraus folgt die Existenz von *x*”, where the actual domain and properties were already mentionen earlier.
- If you write this to bring *x* in scope for doing further work on it, I would say something like “Sei *x* ∈ *A* sodass *P*(*x*). (N.b.: Existenz eines solchen *x* folgt aus Mustermann et al. 1999)”
- If this is just a side remark regarding something the reader is probably already familiar with, just hand-wave something simple like “es gibt *x* ∈ *A* mit *P*(*x*)” or “*P*(*x*) gilt für gewisse *x* ∈ *A*”.

Comment: I do not agree that "ein" would be read as "genau ein".

Comment: I totally agree with @CarstenS. *Es gibt ein x* or *Es existiert ein x* just states existence of at least one x. If it's exactly one, it would be *genau ein x*.

Comment: I didn't say it _states_ ∃!, only that it _suggests_ it. Yes, if you want to express precisely ∃! then you need to say “genau ein”. If you want to express precisely ∃ then you should say neither “genau” nor “ein”. Again, this doesn't always matter; if it can be looked up elsewhere what some theorem states exactly then “ein / eines” is alright if it improves the sentence structure. But for results of your own, it's no good leaving any possible ambiguity.

Comment: You're wrong. There is no ambiguity.at all. Neither ∃ nor ∀ have anything to do with quantity.

Comment: @Olafant ∀ does not have to do with quantity, but ∃ has to do with quantity. It's exactly what it's all about: that the quantity is **1 or larger**.